# How can I store sequence in an array in MIPS?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I have this homework problem .

Write a program that produces the following sequence; 1,2,2,4,8, 32, 256,… and stores it in an array, depending on the number of terms chosen by the user. Each element in the sequence can be calculated by multiplying the two elements preceding it. In other words the nth sequence number Sn is calculated by the equation Sn=Sn-1×Sn-2.

I tried but it didn't run

My code

^ 
^

```
# UNTITLED PROGRAM

    .data   # Data declaration section
str1: .ascii "Please enter the number of terms to produce: "
arr: .space 40

    .text

main:       # Start of code section


li $v0, 4   # system call code for printing string = 4
la $a0, str1    # load address of string to be printed into $a0
syscall         # call operating system to perform print operation


li $v0, 5   # get ready to read in integers
syscall     # system waits for input
move $s0,$v0    # store the result of the read (returned in $v0) in num1


la $s1,arr
addi $t2,$zero,2    # i=2
addi $t0,$zero,1
add $t1,$t0,$t0
sw $t0,0($s1)
sw $t1,0($s1)

L1:
addi $t2,$t2,1       #i++
addi $s1,$s1,4
lw $t4,0($s1)        #A[i-1]
lw $t5,4($s1)
mul $t3,$t4,$t5
sw $t3,8($s1)
beq $t2,$s0,print 
j L1

print:
lw $t3,0($s1)
li $v0, 1   # system call code for print_int
move $a0, $t3   # integer to print
syscall     # print it
addi $s1,$s1,4
beq $t2,$s0,Exit 
j print


Exit:
li $v0, 10      # exits program
syscall




# END OF PROGRAM
```

Comment: What debugging effort have you made? Where do you think the problem lies?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta   I used stack to save result then sort in array ..but my code did'nt run .. In the end, coding program __ for loop =>A[i]=A[i-1]*A[i-2]
 I think the problem how load word & sort word instruction from array

Answer (score 4):

MARS error message:

> Error in  line 26: Runtime exception at 0x00400030:
>   store address not aligned on word boundary 0x1001002d

The error message is telling you that you're trying to access memory with an illegal (non word-aligned) address at this instruction:

```
sw $t0,0($s1)
```

When you have problems like this, you need to use the debugger. First, set a break point at the instruction where the exception is thrown.

[image: brkpt]

Run the program, and when it stops at the break point, check the address (in $s1) you're trying to access. You'll see that it's `268501037` or `0x1001002d`, and since it ends with a 7, it's not word-aligned.

[image: regfile]

`$s1` has the correct array address, but I think you're assuming that when you created the array in the data segment, that it would start at a word-aligned address. This is not the case. To resolve this, you need to [align](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/MIPS_Instructions#Directives) the data.

```
    .data   # Data declaration section
str1: .ascii "Please enter the number of terms to produce: "
    .align 2
arr: .space 40
```